# Creating a Looped query in MySQL without a function or stored proc

Tags: mysql

I need to generate  a report aggregating data over 2 week intervals. 
I've  made  the logic for iterating over 2 weeks successfully but in order to increase the interval I need a loop. Currently I have:

```
SET @start_date = '2019-09-01';
WHILE (@start_date < CURDATE() &&  SUBDATE(@start_date, INTERVAL -2 WEEK) < CURDATE()) DO

SELECT ac.ACCOUNT_ID, ac.ACCOUNT_NAME, COUNT(rc.rec_id) as 'Total Biweekly Payments', @start_date as 'Start Day', SUBDATE(@start_date, INTERVAL -2 WEEK) as 'End Day'
FROM Account ac
INNER JOIN payment_record rc ON rc.ACCOUNT_ID = ac.ACCOUNT_ID
WHERE ac.PARENT_ACCOUNT_ID = '839912'
    AND rc.dept_id = 'R&D'
    AND (
        rc.LAST_UPDATE_DATETIME >= @start_date AND ap.LAST_UPDATE_DATETIME < SUBDATE(@start_date, INTERVAL -2 WEEK)
    )
GROUP BY ac.ACCOUNT_NAME;

SET @start_date = SUBDATE(@start_date, INTERVAL -2 WEEK);
END WHILE;
```

The error I'm getting is:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHILE (@start_date < CURDATE() &&  SUBDATE(@start_date, INTERVAL -2 WEEK) < CURD' at line 3

From my research and a previous post I've seen that this sort of syntax on IF statements doesn't work outside of stored procs or functions problem is being a non-dba I don't have create or delete permissions so I can't make a stored proc.

Is this possible? Without a stored proc or function?

EDIT: 
- Version: 5.7.25-28-log (That's what comes back from Select Version())

Comment: WHILE is a key word usually found in stored procedures. I think you will want to look into windowing functions found in MySQL 8

Comment: MySQL supports the IF, CASE, ITERATE, LEAVE LOOP, WHILE, and REPEAT constructs for flow control within stored programs -https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-statements.html so not possible.

Comment: Can you add your select statement please and you mysql version.

Comment: Are you able to create an `Anonymous Blocks`? Or even that's needs additional privileges?

Comment: @Arun Palanisamy Anonymous Blocks are an oracle thing that don't exist in mysql..

Comment: @P.Salmon Oh Alright! Thanks for the information :)

Comment: @P.Salmon I added the sql version. And the query I have in the select, the select clause works fine for 1 bi-weekly interval but I need to run it for successive previous months, which is why I have start_date bound to a variable that I can change as needed

Comment: @DaveStokes Windowing? I took a look at the docs but I don't these match my use case.